# What is a module variable vs. a global variable?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, global-variables

From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40941211/774575): "*global* in Python basically means at the module-level". However running this code in a file named `my_module.py`:

```
import my_module as m

foo = 1
m.bar = m.foo + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('foo:', foo)
    print('m.foo:', m.foo)
    print('m.bar:', m.bar, '\n')

    for attrib in ('foo', 'bar'):
        print("'{0}' in m.__dict__: {1}, '{0}' in globals(): {2}".format(
            attrib,
            attrib in m.__dict__,
            attrib in globals()))
```

Output:

```
foo: 1
m.foo: 1
m.bar: 2 

'foo' in m.__dict__: True, 'foo' in globals(): True
'bar' in m.__dict__: True, 'bar' in globals(): False
```

What exactly are the module and global namespaces?

Why is there a `__dict__` attribute in module namespace but not in global namespace?

Why is `m.bar` part of `__dict__` and not part of `globals()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are basically 3 different *kinds* of scope in Python:

- module scope (saves attributes in the modules `__dict__`)
- class/instance scope (saves attributes in the class or instance `__dict__`)
- function scope

(maybe I forgot something there ...)

These work almost the same, except that class scopes can dynamically use `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` to simulate the presence of a variable that does not in fact exist. And functions are different because you can pass variables to (making them part of their scope) and return them from functions.

However when you're talking about global (and local scope) you have to think of it  in terms of visibility. There is no *total global scope* (except maybe for Pythons built-ins like `int`, `zip`, etc.) there is just a *global module scope*. That represents everything you can access in your module.

So at the beginning of your file this "roughly" represents the module scopes:

[image]

Then you `import my_module as m` that means that `m` now is a reference to `my_module` and this reference is in the global scope of your current file. That means `'m' in globals()` will be True.

[image]

You also define `foo=1` that makes `foo` part of your global scope and `'foo' in globals()` will be `True`. However this `foo` is a total different entity from `m.foo`!

[image]

Then you do `m.bar = m.foo + 1` that access the global variable `m` and changes **its** attribute `bar` based on `m`s attribute `foo`. That doesn't make `m`s `foo` and `bar` part of the current global scope. They are still in the global scope of `my_module` but you can access `my_module`s global scope through your global variable `m`.

[image]

I abbreviated the module names here with `A` and `B` but I hope it's still understandable.

Comment: I have one question though: Is there an actual use-case to import the module in itself? Or was it just curiosity?

Comment: Not a real case. Just trying to compare content of `__dict__` and `globals()`. I couldn't without importing.